# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Kreait\Firebase\ServiceAccount' not found in

Tags: php, firebase

I have to learn just now write mobile app web service via fire base.
I followed this link: https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

In my core website i create web service folder and then create my fire.php file.This file code here,

```
<?php

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;
use Kreait\Firebase\ServiceAccount;

$serviceAccount = ServiceAccount::fromJsonFile(__DIR__.'/google-service-account.json');
$apiKey = 'AIzaSyC_vb5G9qs3NJsywbR34el1RaPj2HDhwNg';

$firebase = (new Factory)
    ->withServiceAccountAndApiKey($serviceAccount, $apiKey)
    ->withDatabaseUri('https://workarea-cb10b.firebaseio.com')
    ->create();

$database = $firebase->getDatabase();

$newPost = $database
    ->getReference('blog/posts')
    ->push([
        'title' => 'Post title',
        'body' => 'This should probably be longer.'
    ]);

$newPost->getKey(); // => -KVr5eu8gcTv7_AHb-3-
$newPost->getUri(); // => https://my-project.firebaseio.com/blog/posts/-KVr5eu8gcTv7_AHb-3-

$newPost->getChild('title')->set('Changed post title');
$newPost->getValue(); // Fetches the data from the realtime database
$newPost->remove();
```

I have to call my support file here: https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php/

But still I got a:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Kreait\Firebase\ServiceAccount'
>   not found in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/workarea/webservice/firebase/fire.php:13 Stack
>   trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/workarea/webservice/firebase/fire.php on line 13

issue have to fix this issue. Kindly check and help me.

My `composer.json` file

```
{
    "name": "kreait/firebase-php",
    "description": "Firebase Admin SDK",
    "keywords": ["firebase", "google", "sdk", "api", "database"],
    "homepage": "https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        { "name": "Jérôme Gamez", "homepage": "https://github.com/jeromegamez" }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.0",
        "ext-mbstring": "*",
        "ext-openssl": "*",
        "fig/http-message-util": "^1.1",
        "google/auth": "^0.11.0|^1.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.2.1",
        "kreait/firebase-tokens": "^1.1.1",
        "lcobucci/jwt": "^3.2",
        "mtdowling/jmespath.php": "^2.3"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "^2.0",
        "phpstan/phpstan-phpunit": "^0.9.2",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^6.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Kreait\\": "src"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Kreait\\Tests\\": "tests"
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "platform": {
            "php": "7.0"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "3.x-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can we see your composer.json file?

Comment: This is my composer file

Comment: No, it's your fire.php file

Comment: sry i cannot sent my composer file properly.i will sent file via comment

Comment: {
                "name": "kreait/firebase-php",
                "description": "Firebase Admin SDK",
                "keywords": ["firebase", "google", "sdk", "api", "database"],
                "homepage": "https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php",
                "license": "MIT",
                "authors": [
                {
                "name": "Jérôme Gamez",
                "homepage": "https://github.com/jeromegamez"
                }

Comment: ],
                "require": {
                "php": "^7.0",
                "ext-mbstring": "*",
                "ext-openssl": "*",
                "fig/http-message-util": "^1.1",
                "google/auth": "^0.11.0|^1.0",
                "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.2.1",
                "kreait/firebase-tokens": "^1.1.1",
                "lcobucci/jwt": "^3.2",
                "mtdowling/jmespath.php": "^2.3"
                },

Comment: "require-dev": {
                "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "^2.0",
                "phpstan/phpstan-phpunit": "^0.9.2",
                "phpunit/phpunit": "^6.0"
                },
                "autoload": {
                "psr-4": {
                "Kreait\\": "src"
                }
                },

Comment: "autoload-dev": {
                "psr-4": {
                "Kreait\\Tests\\": "tests"
                }
                },
                "config": {
                "platform": {
                "php": "7.0"
                },
                "sort-packages": true
                },
                "extra": {
                "branch-alias": {
                "dev-master": "3.x-dev"
                }
                }
                }

Comment: Edit your question. Don't use comments like this, please.

Comment: sry sir.I sented

Comment: This is the composer.json of the package that you want use - we need _your_ composer.json file

Comment: sir i used ubudu os system

Comment: How can i sent composer file

Comment: I sented my xampp server in composer file pls check it

Answer (score 1):

I am sure you already got your problem solved, but for upcoming developers it might be helpful, Its issue with your composer **install kreait/firebase-php using composer**  in **cmd** inside **project directory** and your issue will be resolved.

Answer (score -1):

I actually had the same issue and I address it by install php-psr exteion:

```
pecl install psr
```

Created /etc/php/7.x/mods-available/psr.ini with the following lines:

```
; configuration for psr module
; priority=20
 extension=psr.so
```

and enable the extension by excuting:

```
sudo phpenmod psr
```

and reload/restart apache, php-fpm.....

```
service apache2 restart
service php7.4-fpm restart
```

Comment: For everyone reading this, please note that this is recommendation should not be followed without further information on the environment this applies to (system- and project-wise). A class not being found can have multiple reasons, none of which I know warrant the installation of a PECL extension that I never heard of until today 