# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Kreait\Firebase\Factory::getDatabase()

Tags: php, firebase, composer-php

I'm trying to use php with firebase, but I have this error when I'm trying to run the code.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Kreait\Firebase\Factory::getDatabase() in C:\xampp\htdocs\table\includes\db.php on line 10

the db.php file:

```
<?php

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;
use Kreait\Firebase\ServiceAccount;

$firebase = (new Factory())->withServiceAccount(__DIR__.'/bib-bayitback-firebase-adminsdk-lkch9-44e22401ec.json');

$database = $firebase->getDatabase();



?>
```

my composer.json file:

```
{
    "require": {
        "kreait/firebase-php": "5.0"
    }
}
```

how can I solve it?

Comment: DId you see reference? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48023499/fatal-error-uncaught-error-class-kreait-firebase-serviceaccount-not-found-in   and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60397030/uncaught-error-call-to-undefined-method-kreait

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have installed v5.0.0 of the [Firebase Admin SDK for PHP](https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php), but the tutorial you followed is for a 4.x version.

This is an issue that happens so often that [it has its own section in the "Troubleshooting" section in the SDK's documentation](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/troubleshooting.html#call-to-private-undefined-method).

With v5.x, the correct way to initialize a Firebase component is:

```php
$factory = (new Factory())->withServiceAccount(__DIR__.'/bib-bayitback-firebase-adminsdk-lkch9-44e22401ec.json');

$database = $factory->createDatabase();
```

As a side note:

```json
{
    "require": {
        "kreait/firebase-php": "5.0"
    }
}
```

will install version 5.0 and 5.0. only (the current version is 5.13). You will never receive a newer release of the library because you fixed the version constraint to `5.0`.

If you want to be sure to receive new features and bug fixes for the SDK, please add a caret(`^`) in front of the version number:

```json
{
    "require": {
        "kreait/firebase-php": "^5.0"
    }
}
```

This will allow your project to receive the latest 5.x release of the SDK.